# Can't get or delete user by mail but to create new one I can

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot, crud

I'm working on Spring Boot project with CrudRepo
now the findAll() and the save() method working perfectly but when I'm trying to get user or delete user its returns nothing

something that I can't resolve its when I put a regular string as email like "jksahd" or whatever its working but when I put a valid mail like"hsdg2@dsj.com" the delete() and findOne() doesn't work

my code:

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {

private long phoneNumber;
private String name;
private String lastName;
private String country;
private String countryCode;
private boolean isAdmin;
private String Email;
private String password;
private boolean isPaid;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(insertable = false,updatable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@ColumnDefault("1492944369375")
private Date timeStamp = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
private String langSpeak;
private String tradeLvl;

public User(long phoneNumber, String name, String lastName, String country, String countryCode, boolean isAdmin, String email, String password, boolean isPaid, String langSpeak, String tradeLvl) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.country = country;
    this.countryCode = countryCode;
    this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
    this.Email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.isPaid = isPaid;
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    //timeStamp = new Date();
    //setTimeStamp(timeStamp);
    this.langSpeak = langSpeak;
    this.tradeLvl = tradeLvl;
}

public User(){}

@Id
public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}
```

then getters and setters

the service methods

```
public String newUser(User user) {
    if (repo.exists(user.getEmail()))
        return "already exsists";
    repo.save(user);
    return "ok";
}

public User getUserByMail(String mail){
    //return userDao.getUserByMail(mail);
    repo.findOne(mail);
    return repo.findByEmail(mail);
}

public String deleteUserByMail(String mail) {
    if (repo.exists(mail)) {
        repo.delete(mail);
        return "ok";
    }

    return "already deleted";
}
```

the Repo class:

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepo extends CrudRepository<User,String> {
    public User findByEmail(String mail);
}
```

the controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String newUser(@RequestBody User user){
    return userService.newUser(user);
}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{mail}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User getUserByMail(@PathVariable("mail") String mail){
    return userService.getUserByMail(mail);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{mail}",method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String deleteUserById(@PathVariable ("mail") String mail){
    return userService.deleteUserByMail(mail);
}
```

Comment: Just a side note. This constructor is very error prone : `public User(long phoneNumber, String name, String lastName, String country, String countryCode, boolean isAdmin, String email, String password, boolean isPaid, String langSpeak, String tradeLvl)`

Comment: why? but I need those fields

Comment: I know. But setting them with a constructor is error prone as you may mix the order of String arguments when you invoke it and it will all the same compile fine. Using setters or builder is clearly better here.

Comment: May be it's because of @ in email address! One scenario is that youre building your SQL "by hand" (as a string with append() or + operators) instead of using a PreparedStatement.

Comment: but I sending it as a JSONObject so can u show me a code sample?

Comment: in sequel its looks like an email...